# Use an external editor for some file types with Netbeans

Tags: netbeans

So with eclipse I would instruct it to open html/css/js files in textmate, and pretty much just use if for the php side of things.

Would like to do a similar thing with nb if possible.

Any thoughts?

Best, 
Bob

Comment: Is this question still relevant?

Answer (score 5):

There exists a [Path Tools](http://plugins.netbeans.org/PluginPortal/faces/PluginDetailPage.jsp?pluginid=676) plugin for Netbeans. It has a command "**Edit path...**". With this you can select a file in the tree, click "Edit path..." and the file will be opened in an external editor.

You can customize the external program which is called under "Tools" -> "Options" -> "Miscellaneous" -> "Path Tools" -> "Edit Commands For File" .

You can't assign it to specific file types, but at least you can open files without leaving Netbeans.

The webpage of the Path Tools plugin looks not very active, but it works in Netbeans 6.9.1 without problems (Works on My Machine).

It also has other useful actions:

- **Copy Paths Action** Copy the full paths of the files/folder of selected node to the clipboard.
- **Explore Action** Launch the OS File Explorer
- **Shell On Path Action** Launch the OS shell
- **Edit Action** Launch the editor

This plugin should be integrated to Netbeans.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Was hoping there was functionality similar to eclipse though where I can tell it to open an *.html file or whatever with any editor I wanted. This is a stopgap I guess.

Comment: Very good. Works with NB 6.9.1 on W7. A little side note: If someone want to use with VIM be sure to use parameter `--remote-tab-silent` (as last parameter before the path) otherwise NB freezes.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the help on this.

Here is a way for the Path Tools 'Edit' toolbar button to pop up the Windows 'Open With...' dialog box for the selected file.

In Options, Path Tools... 'Edit Commands' 'For File' - change the command to this:

```
rundll32.exe C:\WINDOWS\system32\shell32.dll,OpenAs_RunDLL {path}
```

(Edit: I forgot to say this is for XP - idea is the same for newer Windows)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to deal with manipulating plugins and configs, you can do it this way (valid for version 8.2):

1. Go to Tools > Options > Kepmap
2. search for "path"
3. It defaults to Alt + Shift + L

use that command in any editor window to get the path for the file, then simply open that path in whichever editor.

I agree it's not as smooth and savvy as having a readily-available "open in external editor" command, but it's almost there.